# Underlines everywhere, should be probably removed from the stack snippet

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

A recent change adds underline to all the links within questions/answers/comments which seems to be good but I don't understand why it's added to the stack snippet:

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Those aren't really links so we can probably keep them as they were before?

Comment: These are hyperlinks, too, aren't they? Why should they be an exception?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev in the code they are links but they don't open links, they trigger actions on the post

Comment: There's practice formatting Javascript links with dashed or dotted underline as opposed to solid. Though it's far from being common.

Comment: The purpose of a different color with an underline is basically to say, without needing to hover: "this text is clickable". [Artemy Lebedev elaborated on this subject in his Kovodstvo guide some time ago](https://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/171/).

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev That might be reasonable, if SE used the same formatting for all of their `<a>` which they are really used as buttons (i.e. button-like links). The fact that every single other button-like link on all SE pages are not formatted that way makes it very strange to use this formatting for these button-like links. If there is a desire to indicate what you've stated, then SE should adopt that formatting for *all* of their button-like links, not just these. One way or another, having different formatting for these and all others of these is a bug, or misfeature.

Comment: Button is a different idiom. I couldn't find anything on this, so this is just my hunch: a button means "state transition/active operation", a link is "just go elsewhere, no connection". Note how "execute snippet" and "copy snippet" are buttons while "expand snippet" isn't because the former actively change the data that you work with while the latter only changes view.

Comment: JS links are confusing by default indeed -- they look like regular links but may not "go elsewhere" but instead "transform the current page". That's why the links you encircled are not just links but are accompanied by visual clues that hint that they are not regular links and what they do.

Comment: I concede the lack of an underline could be an _additional_ clue. The tricky part is not to make it look like just a highlighted text (prompting people to pixel-hunt trying to click on the icon rather than the text)...

Answer (score 7):

I'd say that those shouldn't be links anyway, they don't link to anything, they take action. They should be buttons of some form (as should the "add a comment" and such buttons that are currently un-underlined links). They should be visually distinct from the main buttons, but still clearly buttons. (This can be done purely with styling if necessary for pragmatic reasons of not updating the markup in all the places they appear.)

But yes, if they're going to be links that aren't links but are actions, they should be consistently-presented (with or without underlines, uniformly).

Comment: They don't "take action", they only change view of existing information, no changes to persistent data are made.

Comment: Thus the buttons in this case would look "heavy".

Comment: This is part of the change IIRC of making links part of the "button" class in the Stack Style guide. I could be recalling incorrectly, though.

Comment: @canon There's a big difference from UX perspective.

Comment: @canon So I as a user am saying. I want to be damn sure if I do something potentially irrevocable and drastic (like losing unsaved data) by clicking there or not -- before I do it!

Comment: @canon I never generalized it like this, only said that those two types of "actions" are fundamentally different from a user's perspective.

Comment: @canon  A button presents something like an affirmative action with consequences, implies there's a decision to make -- while a link or, say, a tab doesn't. Thus puts a pressure on the user. So, a designer has to decide where and how much pressure is justified so that the UI doesn't exert too much or too little.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev - I don't think a button has anything like that connotation.