# Did I inspire the Stack Overflow Time Machine?

Tags: discussion, april-fools, time-machine

Back in August 2018 [I commented on a post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372725/removing-underlined-links/372749#comment622675_372749) about the 90's-esque link underlines that had recently been introduced on SE.

[image]

Of course, in my mind, this comment *did* actually inspire the [SE April Fools theme of 2019](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382111/announcing-the-stack-overflow-time-machine?cb=1) <sup>1</sup>.

I have already had my tombstone carved and will be retiring from the internet today, satisfied in the knowledge that I indirectly annoyed 100s of thousands of unsuspecting SE users.

You are welcome.

[image]

<sub>1. Please don't destroy my dreams.</sub>

Comment: This question put a legitimate smile on my face.  Whatever anyone else tells you, know this truth in your heart: you inspired the 2019 SO Time Machine gag.  It is as irrefutable as the 2nd law of Thermodynamics, as unquestionable as the sunset.

Comment: The suspense is killing me! Either you die as a hero or live as a heretic.

Comment: @DanBron So I think what you are trying to say is that I should be remembered as one of the greatest heroes of the 21st century?

Comment: @Turnip ***One** of*?

Comment: @Turnip ...or the individual who tried to claim glory amid the suffering of thousands... It honestly is just either extreme, either you'll be loved or hated.

Comment: Then there should have been a turnip in the theme.

Comment: @SurajRao Turnips didn't exists in the 90s.

Comment: @Turnip unicorns did?

Comment: @Script47 I think they were invented in 1989.

Comment: @Script47, Hated! I'm getting a salade tonight, eating all the turnip familly.

Comment: You either die a hero, or live long enough to see yourself become the villain.  In the wake of the carnage that was SO April Fool's 2019, I can only conclude, Turnip, that you didn't die a hero.

Comment: The tombstone needs more unicorns. And maybe a visitor counter.

Comment: "Hero", that's funny.

Comment: Tombstone doesn't have enough sparkles :(

Comment: seems like ya did it.. but by stackexchange rules, the hundreds of thousands of negative opinions of it would have only needed tens of thousands of positives to offset, so you're actually overstocked by 100:1, you wish this legacy buried so soon? onwards brave turnip! there is much to be done!

Comment: @Script47 at least since 400 BC :)... So, that is just before the internet.

Comment: @Turnip You're an absolute legend! You've even inspired them to put the *"Netscape Now! 3.0"* icon on the bottom right of each page on SO.

Comment: Hopefully the root vegetable is proffesional enough to create it's tombstone with notepad, the right way. :P

Comment: @Lundin I had it re-carved. Is that enough unicorns for you?

Comment: @Turnip Beautiful :)

Comment: Turnip it up for what!

Comment: @Turnip make the font comic sans... that'd be the icing (cherry?) on top.

Comment: I wonder if there's some legal issue involved if it turns out it was you who inspired it, intellectual property rights and all that jazz.

Comment: @IanKemp It's funny because it's true...

Comment: @Lundin: Yes, those visitor counters... They were everywhere, including my sites.

Comment: @Lundin we also need the Guestbook log on the tombstone :D

Comment: To the 11 people who downvoted this post, are you disagreeing because you think ***you're*** the inspiration for the Time Machine? If so, please share ;D

Comment: Can I have a corn?

Comment: I see a one eyed pink monster at approx 10 'O' Clock behind that tombstone!

Comment: How do we know you didn't use the time machine to go back and make that comment?

Comment: Even if someone tells you it was their own idea, @Turnip, you can always argue [they saw your comment but just don't remember about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptomnesia) ;)